# parsing to an expression tree in python

Tags: python

I have a genetic program that prints the expression tree to a file (it can easily switch between pre/post/in-fix)

It seems like pre-fix would be the easiest to parse so I am currently using that.

How would I go about parsing this string using python 2.7? For example, how would I parse the string   +(*(2,1),*(4,3))      ~~~~ which is 2*1+4*3

```
f = open('expression_tree.txt', 'r')
input = f.read()
root_node_operator = input[0]
```

That's about as far as I've gotten. I'm not that familiar with parsing. Thanks!

I have one python program that prints the expression tree data structure and I want to parse it and evaluate it in the next python program.

Or is there a way to pass the expression tree object to the next python program so no parsing is needed? like I have my tree called test_tree in GP.py. Can I somehow get at that from my other file MyBot.py?

Comment: Does the output contain anything else besides numbers and basic operations? If yes, what is the name of the genetic program? (Did you mean genetic programming by any chance?)

Comment: What does your “expression tree data structure” look like? Do you want to make a parser from scratch, or use a more powerful library? Why do you want to split the parsing and the evaluation in two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `+(*(2,1),*(4,3))` with `(+ (* 2 1) (* 4 3))`, then pipe to `scheme`

```
$ echo '+(*(2,1),*(4,3))' | sed 's/\(.\)(/(\1 /g; s/,/ /g' | scheme | sed -n '/;Value: /s///p'
```

If you want to use `python`, please try `pyparsing`.

Comment: @user1018733: The symbol `|` is the Unix `pipe` symbol that is used on the command line. Unix commands alone are powerful, but when you combine them together, you can accomplish complex tasks with ease. Windows `cmd` also has `pipe`, but people always use GUI tools in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, prefix notation won't require any parentheses - you control the precedence of operations purely by the ordering of elements in the string. For instance, if you wanted `2*(1+4)*3` instead, your prefix expression would become `"* * 2 + 1 4 3"`.

`2*1+4*3` would become `"+ * 2 1 * 4 3"`. Using split(), this will give you the list of operators and operands, `['+', '*', '2', '1', '*', '4', '3']`. This will take care of the whitespace skipping.  Then to evaluate this, recursively walk the list: if you find an operator, get the next two operands from the list, starting at the current position; if you find a constant, return it. Each time you pull something from the list, advance the current position.

```
opns = {
    '+' : lambda a,b: a+b,
    '-' : lambda a,b: a-b,
    '*' : lambda a,b: a*b,
    '/' : lambda a,b: a/b,
    }

def prefix_eval(expr, posn=0):
    # save current element from expression
    current = expr[posn]

    # advance parsing position
    posn += 1

    if current in ['+','-','*','/']:
        # binary operator, get next two operands
        op1,posn = prefix_eval(expr, posn)
        op2,posn = prefix_eval(expr, posn)

        # evaluate operation from current, on operands
        return opns[current](op1,op2), posn
    else:
        # not an operator, must be a numeric value
        return float(current),posn

print prefix_eval("+ * 2 1 * 4 3".split())[0]
print prefix_eval("* * 2 + 1 4 3".split())[0]
```

prints

```
14.0
30.0
```